# Extract values between special sequence of chars with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some kind of mini template engine that needs to extract values from string between any `%{}%` occurrence.

I've tried to test it with following:

```
const EXTRACT_VALUES = /%{(.*?)}%/g

let testString = 'bla bla %{var1}% bla bla {var11} bla bla %{var22} bla bla %{{var33}}% bla bla %{var4}% bla bla %{ var5 }%'

let values = []
let field
while((field = EXTRACT_VALUES.exec(testString)) != null) {
  values.push(field[1])
}
console.log(values)
```

But the output I get is `["var1", "var22} bla bla %{{var33}", "var4", " var5 "]` when the desired output should be `["var1", "var4", " var5 "]`

What do I need to change in the RegExp in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not allowing the characters `{` and `}` within your captured element with `[^{}]+` instead of a blanket capture, which will invalidate the additional one that you're getting.

```
const EXTRACT_VALUES = /%{([^{}]+)}%/g
```

Comment: While this technically answers the question, I can't help but wonder how someone would insert an escaped `\{` into the string if they wanted.